# How to align text at the border of a container

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I don't know if this is possible easily, but is there a CSS style to align the top of the tallest character with the border of its container?

**HTML**

```
<div><h1>The "T" of this h1 needs to align top (touch the border)</h1></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background:orange;
}
h1 {
    vertical-align:top; //does not seem to work?
}
```

**[JS-Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gem9A/)**

---

Currently, it looks like this
[image]

But it should look like this
[image]

Or like this (`line-height = minimum`?)
[image]

---

### How can I achieve this?

Comment: this does not exactly work as a direct solution but it's acceptable I think http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/Gem9A/2/

Comment: Yes, it's like I usually "solved" it, but I'm looking for a cleaner way which doesn't need maintenance if you change the font/size etc

Comment: have you even tried changing the font-size? it works almost great if you change the font-size, I must say **almost** here, that's why I said ***does not exactly***.

Comment: Yes, I guess I'll stick with this solution if there isn't an "official" way to achieve this. However, I wonder how this value `0.21em` comes into existence. Theoretically, it could be browser specific, right? It should be adjustable with CSS (set to 0) if I look at it reasonably.

Comment: Is it possible to just minimize/remove the `line-height`?

Comment: Removing the line height (i.e. setting it to zero) will mean you can't set a background on the element.

Comment: OK, the background is not needed - it's just for illustration purposes. But I need to have a padding, this seems not work if I have `line-height:0`. Is there another value I can set it to in order to get rid of the line height?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of random, because it depends on the proportions of your font, but you can try something like this:

```
h1 {line-height: .9;}
```

Adjust the line-height value to suit the font. E.g. `line-height: 32px; font-size: 38px;`, or `line-height: 0.9em; font-size: 2em;` etc.

If there isn't enough orange at the bottom, you could always add some bottom border:

```
border-bottom: 20px solid orange;
```

Comment: OK, so you need a "workaround", there is no clean way to achieve this? Isn't it possible to say `line-height:tight/minimum/100%` or something like that?

Comment: Not as far as I know. Each font has its own spacings / line heights etc. There are other solutions I can think of, such as using `::before` or `::after` etc., but all of them are workarounds.